# Como exportar un dato de un archivo Js a otro

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Estaba practicando un poco mis conocimientos sobre JavaScript intentando hacer una App Web en la cual, mediante el uso de una API, se pueda observar todos los países según el continente en el que este. Todo me salio bien, sin embargo necesito ayuda con algo. Quiero que al darle click a un país, me lleve a otra pagina donde me muestre datos mas específicos acerca del mismo, para ello le agregue un Evento de tipo click a cada uno de los países  para así poder determinar el que fue clickeado. Ahora bien, para poder trabajar con los datos de ese país en especifico desde la otra pagina, necesito que me devuelva la informacion que me otorga la API de ese pais para asi poder trabajarlo desde mi otro archivo JS, y no se como puedo hacer eso, estuve intentando con IMPORT y EXPORT pero no logre encontrar la solucion, agradeceria mucho su ayuda, muchas gracias!

Código de la página principal:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.search-bar__input');
let currentRegion = document.querySelector('.current-region');
let openBoxBtn = document.querySelector('.openBtn');
let selectBox = document.querySelector('.select-box');
let continents = document.querySelectorAll('.continent');

currentRegion.textContent = 'america';

openBoxBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    selectBox.classList.toggle('select-box--show');
});

continents.forEach(continent => {
    continent.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        currentRegion.textContent = continent.textContent;
        selectBox.classList.toggle('select-box--show');
        cargarPaises();
    })
})

input.addEventListener('keyup', searchCountry)


function searchCountry (){
    let countryName = document.querySelectorAll('.card__country-title');
    let card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    let upper = input.value.charAt().toUpperCase();
    let value = input.value.substr(1,input.value.length);
    for(let i = 0; i < countryName.length; i++){
        if(!countryName[i].textContent.includes(upper + value)){
            card[i].style.display = "none";
        } else{
            card[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
};


async function cargarPaises(){
    try{
        const peticion = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/${currentRegion.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase()}`);
        let datosPaises = await peticion.json();
        console.log(datosPaises);

        if(peticion.status == 200){
            let paises = '';
            datosPaises.forEach(pais =>{
                let population = pais.population;
                paises += `
                <div class="card">
                <div class="flag">
                <a href="countryInfo.html"><img src="${pais.flags.png}" alt="" class="card__img"></a>
                </div>
                <h2 class="card__country-title">${pais.name.common}</h2>
                <p class="card__description" id="population"><span>Population:</span> ${population.toLocaleString('es-ES')}</p>
                <p class="card__description" id="region"><span>Region: </span>${pais.region}</p>
                <p class="card__description" id="capital"><span>Capital: </span>${pais.capital}</p>
                </div>
            `
            document.querySelector('.countries').innerHTML = paises;
            }); 

            let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
            for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
                cards[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                    var paisSeleccionado = datosPaises[i];
                    console.log(paisSeleccionado)
                });
            }
        } else if(peticion.status == 404){
            console.log('Lo siento, no se ha encontrado');
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Lo siento, ha ocurrido un error y no sabemos que fue");
    }
};

cargarPaises();
```

```css
:root{
/* ## Colors */

/* ### Neutral */    
--Dark-Blue: hsl(209, 23%, 22%);
--Very-Dark-Blue: hsl(207, 26%, 17%);
--Very-Dark-Blue: hsl(200, 15%, 8%);
--Dark-Gray: hsl(0, 0%, 52%);
--Very-Light-Gray: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
--White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: var(--Very-Light-Gray);
}

.container{
    width: 1440px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* HEADER */

header{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px var(--Dark-Gray);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: var(--White);
}

header .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: var(--White);
}

header .container .title{
    font-size: 26px;
}

.theme{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.theme i{
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.theme__current{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* MAIN */

main{
    background: var(--Very-Light-Gray);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

main .container{
    overflow: visible;
}

.search-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.search-row .search-bar{
    background: var(--White);
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 52%,.3);
}

.search-row .search-bar .search-bar__icon{
    color: var(--Dark-Gray);
    margin-right:20px ;
}

.search-row .search-bar .search-bar__input{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--Dark-Gray);
    outline: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.search-row .search-bar .search-bar__input::placeholder{
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--Dark-Gray);
}

.select-region{
    width: 220px;
    background: var(--White);
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 52%,.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--Dark-Blue);
}

.select-region .current-region{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.select-region i{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.select-box{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background:var(--White);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 110%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px hsla(0, 0%, 52%,.3);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.select-box p {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box p:hover{
    background: var(--Dark-Blue);
    color: var(--White);
}

/* COUNTRIES */

.countries{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 40px;
}

.card{
    background: var(--White);
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
}

.flag{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flag img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.card__country-title{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card__description{
    margin: 0 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

span{
    font-weight: 800;
}

/* Modificadores */
.select-box--show{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rest Countries App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c5f3b0fc79.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@300;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Where in the world?</h1>
            <div class="theme">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-moon change-theme"></i>
                <p class="theme__current">Dark Mode</p>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <section class="search-row">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass search-bar__icon"></i>                    
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a country..." class="search-bar__input">
                </div>

                <div class="select-region">
                    <h3 class="current-region">Filter by Region</h3>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down openBtn"></i>
                    <div class="select-box select-box--show" id="selectBox">
                        <p id="Africa" class="continent">Africa</option>
                        <p id="America" class="continent">America</p>
                        <p id="Asia" class="continent">Asia</p>
                        <p id="Europe" class="continent">Europe</p>
                        <p id="Oceania" class="continent">Oceania</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="countries">
                <div class="container">

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿No sería más lógico buscar la información de un país en concreto una vez estés en la página de ese país?

Comment: Tengo entendido que no puedes hacer importa exports en este tipo de javascript. Te toca crear en el mismo archivo una función con parámetros que llame a tu API y llamarla dentro del evento que has creado. Suerte